# Export a Python script to FMU

Tags: python, model, fmi

I need to simulate a Python model in Dymola. After research, I am considering the possibility of converting the Python model into a FMU and then loading that in Dymola. Is this possible? How can I convert a Python script into a FMU?

I tried with the FMPy package and I could not export to FM

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available:

- https://github.com/INTO-CPS-Association/unifmu
- https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/PythonFMU
- https://github.com/LBNL-ETA/SimulatorToFMU

(A way without using FMI would be Modelica ExternalLibrary (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/Modelica-ExternalLibrary), a Modelica library that demonstrates how to call external C/C++ and Python-code from Modelica.)